# How to determine the type of the "targetType" parameter in the IValueConverter "Convert" function?

Tags: windows, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, c++-cx

Here is the function signature:

```
Platform::Object^  ConverterImpl::Convert(Object^ value, TypeName targetType, Object^ parameter, String^ culture)
```

How to verify what datatype "targetType" corresponds to? Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
if(targetType.Name == "Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Brush")
```

But there must be a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper syntax is:

```
auto maybeBrush = dynamic_cast<Brush^>(parameter);
if (maybeBrush != nullptr)
{
    // We have a brush, let's do something with it!
}
```

You could also do something like this (taking precautions against dereferencing a null value):

```
if (value->GetType() == Brush::typeid)
{
    // We have a brush here, too!
}
```

An example implementation can be found in the Hilo project, or more conveniently at [this blog post](http://phsucharee.wordpress.com/2013/06/24/data-binding-and-ccx-ivalueconverter/).

Comment: Yes your first example is the right way to do it. It's pretty embarassing to have forgotten dynamic_cast :/

And concerning the second: no I don't need to test the type of the "value" parameter. "targetType" is the type to which we are converting to. This seems to work:

    if(targetType.Name == TypeName(Brush::typeid).Name)
    {
    }